# Proving two intervals are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and cannot seem to figure it out. Suppose I have $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$, both of which are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Just using this fact alone, how would I prove that $(0,3)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. My approach is somehow using the fact that the intersection of the two intervals is connected and then somehow composing functions, but I am unsure on the details.

Comment: The simplest approach is to ignore $(1,3)$ and prove that $(0,3)$ is homeomorphic to $(0,2)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there any way of doing it by using $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$ directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you only know that $J_1 = (0,2)$ and $J_2 = (1,3)$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, then it does not say anything about $(0,3)$. You can either generalize your proof that $J_i \approx \mathbb R$ to arbitrary open intervals $(a,b)$ (which is easy) or construct a homeomorphism $h : (a,b) \to (c,d)$. This is simply given by $h(x) =\frac{x-a}{b-a}(d-c) + c$.